# Linq Lamda expression to select multiple columns from entity class and its navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I'm using repository pattern and have the following entity classes and DTO classes.In my services, i am implementing an interface to get albums(album names) in all category(type) GetAlbumsInAllCategories. I need to return only these fields-abbumcategory.type,song.album,song.albumcover by grouping by these columns, in linq lamda in the function GetAlbumsInAllCategories. The linq lamda expression in the GetAlbumsInAllCategories below gives this error at Select keyword in the line below.

```
return albums.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<AlbumsByCategory, AlbumsByCategoryDTO>);
```

[Error at select keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icxtp.jpg)

The error is because I selected only few columns from repository class AlbumRepository and navigation property song. And I don't want to create a new DTO class for the few selected columns,is there a way to do this without creating a new DTO for the few selected columns but using the existing to AlbumsByCategory and navigation Song?

**T-SQL translation**

```
            select  
        ab.[type],s.Album,s.[AlbumCover]
        from
        [dbo].[AlbumsByCategory] ab
        join [dbo].[Songs] s on s.Id=ab.SongId
        where ab.Archived=0 and ab.ShowByAlbums=1
        group by 
        ab.[type],s.Album,s.[AlbumCover]
```

**Result**
[Result of SQL query above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1orR.jpg)

**AlbumsByCategory**

```
         public partial class AlbumsByCategory
        {
            public int Album_Song_Id { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public int SongId { get; set; }
            public bool ShowByAlbums { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> FromDate { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> ToDate { get; set; }
            public bool Archived { get; set; }
            public virtual Song Song { get; set; }
        }
```

**Song**

```
            public partial class Song
            {
                [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
                public Song()
                {
                    this.Favorites = new HashSet<Favorite>();
                    this.HitMiscSongs = new HashSet<HitMiscSong>();
                    this.PlayListSongs = new HashSet<PlayListSong>();
                    this.AlbumsByCategories = new HashSet<AlbumsByCategory>();
                }

                public int Id { get; set; }
                public string Title { get; set; }
                public string Artist { get; set; }
                public string Genre { get; set; }
                public string AlbumCover { get; set; }
                public string Album { get; set; }
                public string ContentType { get; set; }
                public string FilePath { get; set; }

                [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
                public virtual ICollection<Favorite> Favorites { get; set; }
                [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
                public virtual ICollection<HitMiscSong> HitMiscSongs { get; set; }
                [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
                public virtual ICollection<PlayListSong> PlayListSongs { get; set; }
                [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
                public virtual ICollection<AlbumsByCategory> AlbumsByCategories { get; set; }
            }
```

**DTO clases**

```
 public class AlbumsByCategoryDTO
{
    public int Album_Song_Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int SongId { get; set; }
    public bool ShowByAlbums { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> FromDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> ToDate { get; set; }
    public bool Archived { get; set; }
    public virtual SongDTO Song { get; set; }
}
public class SongEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string AlbumCover { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FavoriteEntity> Favorites { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PlayListSongEntity> PlayListSongs { get; set; }

}
```

**Linq Lamda of the above TSQL in GetAlbumsInAllCategories**

```
            public class AlbumServices : IAlbumServices
            {
                private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
                /// <summary>
                /// Public constructor.
                /// </summary>
                public AlbumServices(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
                {
                    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;

                }

                public IEnumerable<AlbumsByCategoryEntity> GetAlbumsInAllCategories()
                {
                    var albums = _unitOfWork.AlbumRepository.GetAll()
                        .Where(y => y.Archived == false && y.ShowByAlbums == true)
                        .GroupBy(y => new { y.Type, y.Song.Album, y.Song.AlbumCover })
                        .ToList()
                        .SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => new { y.Type, y.Song.Album, y.Song.AlbumCover }));

                    if (albums.Any())
                    {

                            return albums.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<AlbumsByCategory, AlbumsByCategoryDTO>);

                    }
                    return Enumerable.Empty<AlbumsByCategoryDTO>();

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

its a bit confusing on what you are trying to do but it looks like your select is missing the function operator (s =>) and maybe the new keyword to create the return object.

```
Select(s => new Mapper.Map<AlbumsByCategory, AlbumsByCategoryDTO>)
```

Secondly i never use the mapper object that is created when you use the DTO tool.  I created a base class for all my DTO objects and have a constructor that takes an Entity and copies everything for me.  I also have a function to go back to to a DTO so its a 2 way street.  It will only copy the properties that exist so you can have a partial object and it wont fail if some of the properties dont exist.

```
public class DTOBase
{
    public DTOBase() { }
    public DTOBase(Object Entity)
    {
        if (Entity == null) return;
        Type tObjFrom = Entity.GetType();
        Type tObjTo = this.GetType();

        var listPropObj1 = tObjFrom.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetValue(Entity) != null).ToList();

        foreach (var item in listPropObj1)
        {
            if (tObjTo.GetProperty(item.Name) != null)
            {
                tObjTo.GetProperty(item.Name).SetValue(this, item.GetValue(Entity));
            }
        }
    }
    public void MapToEntity(object Entity)
    {
        if (Entity == null) return;
        Type tObjTo = Entity.GetType();
        Type tObjFrom = this.GetType();

        var listPropObj1 = tObjFrom.GetProperties().ToList();

        foreach (var item in listPropObj1)
        {
            if (tObjTo.GetProperty(item.Name) != null)
            {
                //if (item.GetValue(this) != null)
                tObjTo.GetProperty(item.Name).SetValue(Entity, item.GetValue(this));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SO when i am running my Linq from the database i just create the DTO on the fly.

.ToList()
   .Select(s => new EmployeeDTO(s))

If you want to go from the DTO back to an entity you do this...

```
EmployeeDTO.MapToEntity(Employee)
```

Comment: The error I got is simple,there is no class that matches the few fields i selected in my code  below.don't want to create a new class for few fields returnd by query.Is there a way to use existing class to return just the few columns? var albums = _unitOfWork.AlbumRepository.GetAll()
                        .Where(y => y.Archived == false && y.ShowByAlbums == true)
                        .GroupBy(y => new { y.Type, y.Song.Album, y.Song.AlbumCover })
                        .ToList()
                        .SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => new { y.Type, y.Song.Album, y.Song.AlbumCover }));

Comment: I posted a second answer that hopefully addresses your problem.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you are trying to select a few fields from your initial query and only return some of them.  If you do not want to create a special class (we call these Models) then you are stuck with Anonymous Types.  This is hard to use if you plan on passing the results around to other functions or to query against it further.  here is an expample of a linq query with specific fields being selected from the multiple tables into an anonymous type.

```
var seg = context.TaskSegments
                        .Where(s => s.SegmentID == ID)
                        .Select(s => new
                        {
                            SegmentID = s.SegmentID,
                            TaskID = s.TaskID,
                            TaskType = s.Task.Type,
                            DisplayAs = s.Task.DisplayAs,
                            Value = s.Value,
                            CompletedOn = s.CompletedOn,
                            ModifiedBy = s.ModifiedBy,
                            ModifiedOn = s.ModifiedOn,
                            RequiresCompleteDate = s.Task.RequiresCompleteDate,
                            AllowAttachments = s.Task.AllowAttachments,
                            UseYesNoCompletion = s.Task.UseYesNoCompletion,
                            DisplayXWhenNotCompleted = s.Task.DisplayXWhenNotCompleted,
                            Responsible = s.Task.Responsible,
                            Secondary = s.Task.ResponsibleSecondary,
                            Confirmation = s.Task.Confirmation
                        })
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```